# Why is my google cloud function not recognizing a dependency?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement a google cloud function to search text in my firestore database. The sample that I am following is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search?provider=algolia. When I try to deploy my function I get following error:

```
ReferenceError: algoliasearch is not defined
```

I tried running `npm install algoliasearch` which executed successfully however I get the same error.

Here are my dependencies in my `package.json` file which is located in my functions folder:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^2.3.7",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.10.3",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.4",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.4"
  },
```

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
// Initialize Algolia, requires installing Algolia dependencies:
// https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/getting-started/#install
//
// App ID and API Key are stored in functions config variables
const ALGOLIA_ID = functions.config().algolia.app_id;
const ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY = functions.config().algolia.api_key;
const ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY = functions.config().algolia.search_key;

const ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME = 'usernames';
const client = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_ID, ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY);
```

`algoiasearch` is not a user-defined function.

Comment: You're probably installing in the wrong folder. Are you going into the `functions` folder? Check the package.json file under `your_project/functions/`

Comment: @JoelHager Yes I am running all of these commands in the functions folder

Comment: Are you importing/invoking it correctly? I'd check the documentation to double-check, just for sanity's sake. :)

Comment: I don't think `ReferenceError` has something to do with dependency being installed. It's more like you are using a variable that you have not defined - could be a typo. Can you please share the code where you are getting this error including how you are importing everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're importing/requiring `algoliaSearch` at all. Your function code should have something at the top like

```
const algoliaSearch = require('algoliasearch')
// ...rest of your code
```

see guide https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/instantiate-client-index/

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError),

> The ReferenceError object represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced.

That being you are not importing it similar to the documentation is missing the import as well.

```
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch"
```